# Heroku app run locally not updating changes to code after refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, heroku, mean-stack

I'm working with this tutorial [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api) and I've set it up locally also. When I run it using "heroku local" it lunches and connect to the database, I am able to add/update/delete contacts and they all reflect on mlab.

Anyways, I'm changing some simple html in one of the components and it will not update locally, when I push it to heroku thought it updates and they are visible on the online app hosted by heroku.

1. I've disabled caching
2. Cleared Caching
3. Cleared Caching using dev tools
4. Setting NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false also did not work

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your component is not being updated is because it needs to be rebuilt. Each time you deploy your app to Heroku it will be built on their servers.

In order to keep your app always up to what you're coding, you need to "watch" it. The easiest way to do it for an angular 2+ project is using the [Angular Cli](https://cli.angular.io/). If you want to do it your own, you can configure your own Webpack file (or Gulp or whatever you like).

Comment: By watch it you mean ng serve? That for some reason does not allow me to connect to the DB

Comment: That's because that command doesn't run your DB! If you want to have more control you can `ng eject` and get a webpack.conf, but you'll lose some important ng scripts. You can btw connect to your DB in another terminal. How do you​ connect to it?

Comment: I connect to it using server.js that takes in the mlab string and calls the data.

Comment: Fine, run `node server.js` and `ng serve` in TWO separate terminals and you'll see your app being updated while you modify it, connected to your DB.

Comment: Glad could help :) but have in mind that you're entering in the world where more than one terminal is pretty common on development, so when you open one ask to yourself "what am I doing with it? What not?" don't just follow a tutorial blindly!